# Distinguishing between different types of elliptical polarization

Tags: optics, visible-light, soft-question, polarization

How to distinguish between a mixture of plane polarized and unpolarized light, and a mixture of
elliptically polarized and unpolarized light?

When we pass plane polarized wave though quarter wave plate it becomes elliptically polarized light and unpolarized light remains the same . So when this light is passed through a rotating polaroid we get intensity having 2 maxima and 2 undiminished minima. Now for 2nd part elliptically polarized wave when passed through the same plate we get plane polarized and unpolarized remains same and when this type is passed we get intensity having 2 maxima and 2 undiminished minima. So how do we differentiate the two types?

Comment: Hello and welcome to the Physics StackExchange. Could you add more context and details, please?

Comment: @Abhigyan For example:- To differentiate circularly polarized light and unpolarized light  we can use a quarter wave plate and then rotate Polaroid . If this exp is done circularly polarized light becomes plane polarized and after passing through rotating Polaroid we get intensity having 2 maxima and 2 completely extinguished minima but for unpolarized light we get no variation of intensity .  But if we do the same exp. for types of light given above in the question we can't distinguish it.

Comment: @Gourab I recommend you learn about the Stokes parameters for describing the polarization of light: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes_parameters. Then you can google "how to measure the Stokes parameters"

Comment: [These results](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4757/79678) will be at the link for a couple of days. They nicely corroborate the given answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just rotate the quarter-waveplate to achieve maximum contrast. This way you ensure that whichever light falls onto your detection will extinguish to the unpolarized minimum. What you effectively do is make sure that after the quarter waveplate you always get linearly polarized light: in the case of linearly polarized light, this means aligning the quarter waveplate to match the light's polarization either on it's slow or fast axis, while for the elliptically polarized light you align the fast/slow axis to those of the ellipse. In both these cases light will come out linearly polarized after the quarter waveplate and rotation of a polarizer will show you the greatest contrast between maxima and minima.

EDIT:

To find if you have elliptical+unpolarized or linear+unpolarized, first find quarter-waveplate angle (via rotation) which results in the highest possible contrast between maxima and minima after rotation of the polarizer. Then remove quarter-waveplate and compare the new contrast between maxima and minima. If the quarter waveplate setup had a higher contrast, then the incoming light is elliptical+unpolarized, if the contrast is about the same, then it is linear+unpolarized.

Comment: I don't get how rotating the quarter wave plate will achieve maximum contrast. I am new to this topic so it would be helpful if you could explain it.       I have two types (elliptical & unpolarized) & ( plane polarized & unpolarized). I don't know which one of them is coming towards wave plate. I want to know how we will differentiate these two types.

Comment: I did explain on my answer why it achieves maximum contrast for both elliptical and linear polarizations. When the quarter waveplate axis match those of the ellipse (by rotation), the output light will be linearly polarized and hence, the following polarizer will give the highest contrast. If you need to find out if your light is elliptical+unpolarized or linear+unpolarized, maximize contrast by rotating quarter waveplate and then repeat measurement without waveplate. If the contrast is the same, this means it was linearly polarized, if contrast is higher with waveplate, then it's elliptical.

Comment: @JoséAndrade thanks, now I got it.

Comment: @EdV i don't have 15 rep :333333